# Modelling key top

Tags: modeling, mesh

I started with blender pretty recently. I'm trying to model a key. The stem portion is almost done but I'm unable to proceed with the key top. How to model the clover shape in the key top and join with the rest of the model? [image: key top to model]

Comment: are they supposed to be flat or round rings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let say that you want it round, I would do it this way:

- Create 3 torus (24 major segments, 12 minor segments).
- Scale down the third torus, then scale up its radius with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> so that it keeps about the same thickness as the others.
- *Boolean* them (*Union* mode).
- Cut them.
- Merge the vertices that need to be merged with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.
- Create the central spike with some extrusions and scales.
- Select a sphere and extrude it to create the handle.
- Merge the handle with the rest of the key with some <kbd>F</kbd> (Fill).
- Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and in *Tools* > *Shading* > *Smooth*.

[image]